# Backup-SPsite command

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I want to use the `Backup-SPsite` powershell command to backup my SharePoint Enterprise 2013 site collection but want to keep only a week worth of backups

A backup will run everyday Monday to Sunday and then the oldest backups are overwritten, also an email notification to say the backup with successful would be great.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes, but you will need to write a PS script doing all the described work for you instead of just a single command.
You can get more useful info about Backup-SPSite command [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff607901(v=office.15).aspx). Also you can find good examples of usage of Backup-SP* commands [here](http://tutorial.programming4.us/windows_server/Using-SharePoint-2010%E2%80%99s-Catastrophic-Backup-Cmdlets.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using powersehll. Refer this [article](http://maraboustork.co.uk/2010/10/using-powershell-to-set-up-an-sptimerjob/).

For sending email use powershell command `Send-MailMessage`. More on this from [here](http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/powershell-sending-email-with-gmail-example)

Comment: Why should we create a TimerJob in SharePoint instead of running a powershell script as a scheduled task in this scenario? And if we use a timer job, why not send the email from the SharePoint code?